# Github: Configure username

Tags: git, github

In Github, when someone in the team push some changes, we can see his/her username with a link to their Github account, like the green one here:

[image]

In my case (red) it is just the text of my username.

I configured the user name and email with:

```
git config user.name "pmirandaarias"
git config user.email "myemail@example.com"
```

What should I do?

Comment: where from the screen shot was taken? mention the specific location!

Comment: Most likely your email address doesn't match any email addresses setup in your github account.

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple 3 steps approach/

**Step-1:**

Clone your Work repository and Private repository to your laptop/desktop.
We will use different username and email for each repository.

**Step-2:**

- Go to repository
- Click on hidden folder `.git`
- Open config file

**Step-3:**
Add `[user]` tag with username and email info. Here is a sample.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/bla/bla/bla/bla
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[user]
    name = YourName, LLC
    email = email [at] site.com
```

**Using command line also you could to change the file.**

- Open macOS Terminal.
- Change the current working directory to the local repository
- This is a repository where you want to configure the name that is
  associated with your Git commits.
- Execute command: `git config user.email "email [at] site.com"`
- Execute command: `git config user.name "YourName, LLC"`

Comment: But I already have set user.email and user.name, I can see those values under `config` file

Comment: well this is the way we do. Question was to add link to your name in git, Right?? If no then I will say just remove your user info from config and then try again.